# Spring batch DELETE BEFORE INSERT best practice?

Tags: spring-batch, best-fit

In a Spring Batch job, i need to code a DELETE before an INSERT in order to avoid primary key violations on already existing keys.

What is the best practice regarding this need ?
How and where should i implement this pre-requisited delete ?

Thx in advance for your suggestions.
:-)

Comment: what about use an update?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should insert the data in some `temp table` before deleting it from actual table because what if you delete record and insert fails?

The data will be lost or either use `spring transactions` to avoid this failure, in case something un-expected happens it roll-backs the whole transaction.

This is something like how we did for `safe file writing`.

Comment: Thx Pankaj for your suggestions. What do you mean with "safe file writing" please ?

Comment: Its basically a concept in which we are suppose to overwrite an existing file on the hard disk, what if we are writing file and encountered `out of disk space` the operation won't be successful and may be existing data in that file gets corrupted. That's why tmp/rename concepts are more better options at the time of file writing

If the answer makes sense kindly `accept` my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use tasklet to delete the data. For the tasklet to work, you may have to inject jdbcTemplate or similar to execute Db operations from tasklet.
I also reserached this topic on internet and this is the best solution what I got till now.